# iOS 15 / Xcode 13 Cannot generate private key on simulator running iOS 15 with SecKeyCreateRandomKey

Tags: ios, keychain

When running app in Xcode 13 on simulator with iOS 15
Cannot generate random key with `SecKeyCreateRandomKey`

```
let attributes = ...
        var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
        guard
            let privateKey = SecKeyCreateRandomKey(attributes as CFDictionary, &error),
            let publicKey = SecKeyCopyPublicKey(privateKey)
        else {
            let error = error!.takeRetainedValue() as Error
            logger?.log(message: "Random key generation error: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
```

and attributes are

```
let accessControl = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(
            kCFAllocatorDefault,
            kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly,
            .userPresence,
            nil
        )
        return [
            kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
            kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: keySizeInBits,
            kSecPrivateKeyAttrs: [
                kSecAttrIsPermanent: true,
                kSecAttrApplicationTag: encoded(tag: tag),
                kSecAttrAccessControl: accessControl as Any,
            ],
        ]
```

> Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-25293 "Key generation failed,
> error -25293" UserInfo={numberOfErrorsDeep=0, NSDescription=Key
> generation failed, error -25293}

Comment: That error code is `errSecAuthFailed`. What happens if you remove the requirement `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly` or test on a real device with a passcode set?

Comment: facing similar issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I was able to trigger the problem by adapting this sample code: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/accessing_keychain_items_with_face_id_or_touch_id/. It happens on the simulator for iOS 15, doesn't happen on the iOS 14 simulator. Submitted Feedback Assistant issue (FB 9910976).

Answer (score 1):

This was the problematic attribute `.userPresence,`